# Tailwind is not working together with styled material ui components in nextjs 13 in production but work in development

Tags: material-ui, tailwind-css, next.js13

I created a small nextjs project together with tailwind css and material ui.Tailwind css is working fine in development mode but when I build production, tailwind css are no longer working.

```
    "tailwindcss": "3.3.3",
    "next": "13.4.19",
    "@mui/material": "^5.14.8"
```

```
tailwind.config.ts

import { MARGIN_BETWEEN_COMPONENTS } from "./app/constants/constant";

/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      backgroundImage: {
        "gradient-radial": "radial-gradient(var(--tw-gradient-stops))",
        "gradient-conic":
          "conic-gradient(from 180deg at 50% 50%, var(--tw-gradient-stops))",
      },
      fontFamily: {
        custom: ["var(--font-DINPro)"],
      },
      backgroundColor: {
        primary: "#ff9e1b",
      },
      maxWidth: {
        customInput: "230px", // Add your custom maximum width here
      },
      padding: {
        pagePadding: "20px 40px",
      },
      textColor: {
        primary: "#ff9e1b",
      },
    },
  },
  important: "#app",
  plugins: [],
};
```

```
postcss.config.ts

module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
}
```

```
globals.css

@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

:root {
  --foreground-rgb: 0, 0, 0;
  --background-start-rgb: 214, 219, 220;
  --background-end-rgb: 255, 255, 255;
}

@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
  :root {
    --foreground-rgb: 255, 255, 255;
    --background-start-rgb: 0, 0, 0;
    --background-end-rgb: 0, 0, 0;
  }
}

body {
  background-color: white;
  /* padding: 30px 40px; */
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.text-white {
  color: white;
}

.custom-button {
  margin-top: 32px;
  padding-top: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.table-cell {
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: center;
}

.table-cell-head {
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}
```

```
My material button 

import { Button } from "@mui/material";

const CustomButton: React.FC<props> = ({ value, style, onClick }) => {
  return (
    <Button
      variant="contained"
      onClick={onClick}
      className={`bg-primary rounded-3xl hover:bg-primary pt-1 shadow-none ${style}`}
    >
      {value}
    </Button>
  );
};
```

```
next.config.js

/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

I have tried to add "important : true" inside tailwind.config.css but some of tailwind css like hover is no longer working along with other tailwind css styles.

I have also triged selector strategy from tailwind official documentation and same as above result https://tailwindcss.com/docs/configuration#selector-strategy.

I have also tried to create new nextJS project and tested only with Button component.

[Development result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5nh99.png)

[Production result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJmV2.png)

[Folder Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Idk5x.png)

Comment: Don't you think it's an overkill to have tailwindcss as well as Material UI in the same project, anyways, are you using typescript? share your folder structure and also tailwind config details

Comment: Hi, yes. I use typescript as well. I pasted folder structure image in the post. I needed material ui for material table, so I decided to use other material components as well.

Answer (score 1):

Material UI fully supports Tailwind CSS and even provides documentation for it.

The root cause of this issue is that Tailwind CSS styles are applied to the component first, and then Material UI styles are applied. Since my code is primarily styled with Tailwind, all of my styles have been overwritten by Material UI.

**Fix (30 Sep, 2023)**

Follow the official Material UI documentation to inject Material UI styles first, and only then apply Tailwind CSS.

https://mui.com/material-ui/guides/interoperability/#tailwind-css

After following these steps, your problem should be resolved.